# td and th borders go over table borders

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table with sharp corners on the inside and round corners on the outside, but when I do this, the sharp `td` borders go over the rounded table borders at the bottom. I want the bottom row of my table to have rounded corners, like the top row. Is there any way to do this?

Here's a screenshot of what I'm referring to:

[image: Image of issue]

```
td {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
   background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
   border-radius: 20px;
   border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```css
td {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

table {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
      
table tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some text 1</td>
    <td>some text 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some text 3</td>
    <td>some text 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The border radius of the child elements is 0 which makes them square. so yoou have the whole square peg in the round hole thing going.

in addition to @johannesdz answer, you could also add margin to your tableRows to space them out more. or add padding to the bottom of the table.